# Azure App Service Plan (Basic Small) limitations?

Tags: asp.net, azure, crm

We have an ASP.NET WebAPI web service deployed on Azure as an App Service, 
but whenever we call the service, it works continuously for only 8 hours, before it stops with no indication of error.

Is there a CPU time limit that is causing this?

The plan we use is Basic - Small.

Thanks.

Best regards,
Evgeni Dyulgerov

Answer (score 0):

Basic small plan does not have any CPU time limit, you can check the details here :

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#app-service-limits

However, your problem seems to be linked to the *Always On* setting, which is set to false by default. Whenever your App Service is idle for some time, it "pauses" and automatically wakes up when several requests reach your service.

Try set the *Always On* setting to **ON**, as described here :
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure/

Comment: I tried your advice, but the issue hasn't disappeared. I tried to debug the web service in Azure (I found an error that I fixed), but after working for a few hourse, my debug session was disconnected and the service stopped again. Do you have any other suggestion that I can try?